# How to determine if a class is decorated with a specific attribute

Tags: vb.net, attributes

I'm trying to determine if a interface is decorated with a specific attribute.  For example, I have the following interface:

```
<MyCustomAttribute()> _
Public Interface IMyInterface
    Function Function1
    Sub DeleteWorkflowInstanceMap(ByVal instanceId As Guid)
    Sub InsertWorkflowInstanceMap(ByVal instanceId As Guid, ByVal aliasName As String)
End Interface
```

How do I determine if IMyInterface is decorated with the MyCustomAttribute attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even better than `GetCustomAttributes` is the Shared method `IsDefined`:

```
Attribute.IsDefined(GetType(IMyInterface), GetType(MyCustomAttribute))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
GetType(IMyInterface).GetCustomAttributes(GetType(MyCustomAttribute), false).Length > 0
```

(I hope I have the VB syntax right.)  Basically get a Type representing IMyInterface, then call GetCustomAttributes on it passing the type of attribute you're interested in.  If that returns a non-empty array, the attribute is present.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-method-attributes-and-reflection