# How to efficiently test if action is decorated with an attribute (AuthorizeAttribute)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, reflection, c#-4.0

I'm using MVC and have a situation where in my `OnActionExecuting()` I need to determine if the Action method that is about to execute is decorated with an attribute, the `AuthorizeAttribute` in particular.  I'm not asking if authorization succeeded/failed, instead I'm asking does the method require authorization.

*For non-mvc people* `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName` is the method name I'm looking for.  It is not, however, the currently executing method; rather, it is a method that will be executed shortly.

Currently I have a code block like below, but I'm not terribly pleased with the looping prior to every action.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] actionMethodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethods();

foreach(System.Reflection.MethodInfo mInfo in actionMethodInfo) {
    if (mInfo.Name == filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName) {
        object[] authAttributes = mInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute), false);

        if (authAttributes.Length > 0) {

            <LOGIC WHEN THE METHOD REQUIRES AUTHORIZAITON>

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a little like the slightly mistitled "[How to determine if a class is decorated with a specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238778/how-to-determine-if-a-class-is-decorated-with-a-specific-attribute)" but not quite.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can simply use filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    bool hasAuthorizeAttribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), false)
        .Any();

    if (hasAuthorizeAttribute)
    { 
        // do stuff
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: ActionDescriptor.IsDefined() can also be used in place of ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes().Any() if you want a slight perf boost.

Comment: Duh...I was already referencing ActionDescriptor in my old clode block.  Sometimes the answer is right in front of you.  Thanks. And thanks @Levi for the additional tip +1.

Comment: I do not have ActionExecutingContext, So I cannot have ActionSescriptor. Instead I am inside the Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest handler in global.asax.cs, so how we can get the attribute there?

Answer (score 10):

`var hasAuthorizeAttribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), false);`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor.isdefined%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

Comment: Beware! if it's the controller the one with the [Authorize] attribute, this won't work. Besides, the action can be decorated with [AllowAnonymous]. I have used this instead:
`var hasAuthorizeAttribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), false) || 
                (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), false) && !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), false));`

Comment: this is not about valid Authorization check, the example about efficient Attribute check. And probably you are right, it could be other fatctors that affect Authorization as well.